# Как подключить Font Awesome 5.8.1 локально (не через CDN)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как правильно подключать font awesome 5, меня интересует только локальный способ, через CDN не предлагать, хочу использовать SVG иконки, подключаю как и положено: помогите кто знает

Подключаю в head

```
<script src="fontawesome/all.js"></script>
```

html-css код:

```
<div class="icon"></div>

.icon::before {
    content: "\f17b";
}
```

Comment: css-файлы то не хотите до кучи подключить?

Comment: @teran в этом нет нужды в пятой версии, если используешь JS

Comment: @alexRoosso при этом в ответе вы пишите, что надо таки подключить?

Comment: Я написал Вам корректное решение для CSS версии FA. Решение которое Вы привели в вопросе, даже при подключении CSS версии не стало бы срабатывать корректно в том же Хроме.

Comment: Ваш вопрос касался SVG версии. Я ответил почему это пока что невыполнимо. Думаю, что в будущем все же стандарты будут расширены и появится возможность так же обращаться и с SVG шрифтами. (Как по мне за этим форматом больше будущего чем за woff или уж тем более ttf)...

Answer (score 1):

У меня для Вас плохие новости. Если хотите использовать HTML сущности или unicode Вам нужно через CSS версию грузить FA.

Когда был написан стандарт SVG, поддержка веб-шрифтов еще не была широко распространена в браузерах. Поскольку доступ к правильному файлу шрифта имеет решающее значение для правильного отображения текста, в SVG была добавлена технология описания шрифтов. Она не совместима с другими форматами, такими как PostScript или OTF, это лишь простое средство вложения информации о глифах в SVG при визуализации.

SVG-шрифты корректно поддерживаются только в Safari.
Эта возможность не была реализована в Internet Explorer, она также была удалена из Chrome 38 (и Opera 25),  разработчики Mozilla отложили ее реализацию на неопределенное время, чтобы сосредоточиться на WOFF. Другие инструменты, такие как плагин Adobe SVG Viewer, Batik и частично Inkscape поддерживают встраиваемые шрифты SVG.

Ява версия FA использует SVG Font... Думаю Вы уже догадались к чему я клоню.

Ниже решение как корректно использовать CSS и вставлять символы FA посредством собственного CSS

```css
.icon::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
  content: '\f641';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i class="fas fa-user"></i>

<span class="icon"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вся информация есть на оф. сайте - **[документация](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself).**

А так же, запросы в поисковик можно и на английском языке писать, в основном там обширней информация.

Добавьте локальные пути к all.css и all.js файлам Font Awesome.
Проверьте пути в css файле, которые ссылаются на шрифты в разных форматах.

Ответ на вопрос на **[англоязычной версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470752/how-to-include-local-file-of-font-awesome-4-1-without-using-cdn)**

Comment: сослаться на мануал это хорошо, конечно, но по правилам сообщества в ответ следует включить не только ссылки но и само решение

Comment: добавьте в Ваш ответ код примера. [полезная информация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)